# If $R$ is a ring with unit element $1$ and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of $R$ onto $R'$, prove that $\varphi(1)$ is the unit element of $R'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Herstein 3.4.20: If $R$ is a ring with unit element $1$ and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism of $R$ onto $R'$, prove that $\varphi(1)$ is the unit element of $R'$.

I don't understand why $\varphi$ needs to be onto for this to be true. I see that in general $$\varphi(x)=\varphi(1x)=\varphi(1)\varphi(x)$$
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(1)\varphi(x)$$

Also, $$\varphi(x)=\varphi(x1)=\varphi(x)\varphi(1)$$
$$\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)\varphi(1)$$

So, $\varphi(1)$ acts as the identity element in $R'$. Is this not correct?

Does $\varphi$ need to be onto?

Comment: It looks like you have shown $\varphi(1)$ acts as identity among all elements of $R'$ that can be written in the form $\varphi(x)$, right? In other words, it acts as identity in $\operatorname{im}\varphi$. This is $R'$ precisely when $\varphi$ is onto.

Comment: Here is a *concrete* example: let $R = R' = {\mathbf Z}/(6)$. Let $f(x) = 3x$. Then $f(x)$ is additive and multiplicative (since $3^2 \equiv 3 \bmod 6$), but $f(1) \not= 1$. Note $f$ is not surjective. You should be made aware that the standard convention of most mathematicians who use algebra in their work (esp. anyone who uses commutative algebra) is that *by definition* a ring homomorphism must satisfy $f(1) = 1$. That is, most mathematicians who use algebra would not call a general additive/multiplicative map between rings a ring homomorphism *unless* it satisfies $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some condition on $\phi$, note that your proof only shows that $\phi(1)$ acts trivially when multiplying elements in the image $\phi(R)$, which does not guarantee that it acts as the identity for all of $R'$.  If, for instance, $\phi(x) = 0$ for all $x\in R$, then you have $0 = \phi(1)\phi(x) = \phi(x) = 0$ but $0$ is not the multiplicative identity.

This is fixed when $\phi$ is onto, in that $\phi(x) = 1_{R'}$ for at least one $x$, in which case $\phi(1) = \phi(1)\cdot 1_{R'} = \phi(1)\phi(x) = \phi(x) = 1_{R'}$.

Answer (score 2):

a simple example that shows what can go wrong when the morphism is not epi- is the projection map of a product ring $R \times R$ (with componentwise addition and multiplication)  which sends $(a,b)$ to $(a,0)$.

the element $(1,0)$ is an identity in the image, but it is distinct from the identity $(1,1)$ of the ring $R \times R$